# When to use "memory" and "storage" keyword in solidity 0.6.0?

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.6.x

From what I've learned and noticed. Please add more point and rectify me if I'm wrong.

**Use of memory keyword**

1)When initialising/declaring `Struct`, `Array` , and `mapping`.

2)In the parameters of functions and constructor. With `string` only.
Not with `uint` or `int` or `address`.

```
function verifier (uint age, address add,string memory location)
```

**Use of storage keyword**

1)storage cannot be newly created in a function. Any storage referenced variable in a function always refers a piece of data pre-allocated on the contract storage (state variable). Any mutation persists after function call.

```
function vote(uint8 toProposal) public validStage(Stage.Vote)  {
    Voter storage sender = voters[msg.sender];
  }
```

Comment: "In the parameters of functions and constructor. With string only" - no, also with arrays.

Comment: "When initialising/declaring Struct, Array , and mapping." - not true for mapping (since you cannot declare one inside a function).